# Densely imbedded vector spaces and the closure of the ball

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

**DEFENITION 1** A Banach space $E_1$ is imbedded in a Banach space $E_0$ if:

1. $x\in E_1 \implies x\in E_0$.
2. The space $E_0$ induces a vector space structure on $E_1$ coinciding with the structure of $E_1$.
3. There exists a constant $C_{01}$ such that $$\|x\|_{E_0}\leq C_{01}\|x\|_{E_1}$$ for all $x\in E_1$.

**DEFINITION 2** The space $E_1$ is densely imbedded in $E_0$ if conditions $1-3$ hold, and also

4. The set $E_1$ is dense in $E_0$.

**LEMMA** If a Banach space $E_1$ is imbedded in a Banach space $E_0$ and does not coincides with it, then the closure in $E_0$ of any ball of $E_1$ is nowhere dense in $E_0$.

**FACT** The set $M$ of algebraic polynomials is dense in $C(0,1)$.

**My thought** The space of algebraic polynomials is not coincides with the space of continuous functions on this interval. So for me the Definition 2 and Lemma contradict each other.

**QUESTION** Where I am wrong? What do I do not understand correct? If the closure of any ball is nowhere dense (the interior of the closure is empty) how one space can be dense in the another space?

[image]

Comment: where have you used definition 2 in your lemma? Does the lemma hold for densely imbedded Banach spaces?

Comment: I think the Lemma is false, as your counter-example shows. Did you quote the Lemma correctly?

Comment: The lemma hold for imbedded Banach spaces which are not coincides. Two spaces which I meant in my question (space of algebraic polynomials and space of continuous functions) are Banach spaces and they do not coincides. So this lemma is about this two spaces. But one of them is densely imbedded in the other. Or I am wrong?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I added a photo.

Comment: The lemma is correct (it is the main argument in the proof of the open mapping theorem). It does not contradict the example about Weierstraß' approximation theorem because the space of polynomials is not Banach (neither for the sup-norm nor for any other norm because countable dimensional Banach spaces are finite dimensional).

Comment: @Jochen Thanks! It was my mistake. But the question is "If the closure of any ball is nowhere dense (the interior of the closure is empty) how one space can be dense in the another space?". I understand that the answer could be like "Because it is". But how to understand it? Also I have a question "Is this lemme correct for densely imbedded BANACH spaces?"

Comment: @Jochen Also. We talk about the Banach space A which is imbedded in the Banach space B. If we take the ball (open) in A then its closure must be in A (because it is complate space). So does this lemma says that "any closed ball in A is not open in B"? Is it correct conclusion? Is it the precise meaning of this lemma?

Comment: The intuitive difference between the situation of the lemma and the mere density of $E_1$ in $E_0$ is that you can appriximate every $x\in E_0$ arbitralily well by elements $y$ of $E_1$ but you can't do so with an additional requirement about the size of $y$ measured by the norm in $E_0$. The lemma can be reformulated as follows: Assume that there is $C>0$ such that, for every $x\in E_0$ and $\varepsilon >0$ there is $y\in E_1$ with $\|x-y\|_0\le \varepsilon$ and $\|y\|_1\le C \|x\|_0$. Then $E_0=E_1$.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you! This reformulation and your comment is very helpfull!